How do I use a variable from another component containing HTML and AngularMaterial Tooltips?
In my Angular project (newest version) I want to display a text containing a tooltip when you hover over it. I use Angular Material for that. For the possible tooltip there are multiple options, so I need a string variable containing some extra HTML and a tooltip. While the extra HTML works with [innerHTML]="variable", the tooltip doesn't. Why is that and how can I fix it?
In component1 I got: <div [innerHTML]="variable"></div>
In component2 I got: let variable = '<span matTooltip="TooltipText"><b>Text</b></span>'
I expect the tooltip and the bold text to work, but only the bold text gets applied, the tooltip isn't there. However when I don't use a variable and just input the content of the variable directly, everything works. So it seems like I just can't apply the tooltip through a variable.

Maybe try this: <div> {{ variable }} </div>

Material Tooltips are not supposed to display rich information by design. https://m2.material.io/components/tooltips#placement

@Razzer Nope, that's what I tried in the beginning, but then it just shows the entire HTML syntax, not just the Text with extra features.

@JSONDerulo I don't understand what that means. I can use the tooltip if I use it directly, I just want it to work from a variable.

A Material Tooltip can only be a string. No rich information (custom markup) is supported. This is a technical limitation by Angular Material. You can create a feature request, but it's highly unlikely that it will be implemented, as it directly contradicts with the Material Design recommendations.

@JSONDerulo But then I should be able to remove the  and it should work, no? But it doesn't. Do you have a recommendation for a workaround for me? I'm new to all of this and I just want to have multiple possible tooltips for different texts. So for example when my object has "Technician" as a job, the tooltip should contain information about what a Technician does. If another object has "Teacher" as a job, it should have a tooltip explaining what a teacher does.

Ah, now I see. innerHTML will not render Angular components or directive. It just takes a string input and renders the HTML directly, without Angular processing. This is why you are not seeing the tooltip.

This question is similar to: Load component via innerHtml in angular5. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@JSONDerulo Thank you for that explanation. So is there an alternative to "innerHTML" then? The double curly braces don't work. I can't imagine that there is no workaround to have different tooltips depending on a variable.

The issue you are facing now is an interesting thing. Before diving into the answer, lets understand the root cause of the issue.
Understanding the Root Cause of the Issue
The challenge you're facing stems from the fact that when a variable is passed to innerHTML, it gets appended to the div at runtime, after the build has been generated and during component rendering. The Angular build output is a JavaScript bundle, and when the inner HTML is executed, the Angular logic fails because the browser can only understand HTML, JS, and CSS. Specifically, the MatTooltip attribute, which is an Angular-specific feature, cannot be interpreted by the browser, leading to the loss of its functionality.
Solution
To circumvent this limitation, it's essential to separate the tooltip and inner HTML. Instead, try the following approach:
  toolTip="TooltipText"
  variable="<b>Text</b>"


<div [matTooltip]="toolTip" [innerHTML]="variable">


Thank you. But can you explain to a beginner like me, how I can then combine tooltip and variable again? Because I want a specific variable to have a specific toolTip. So if the variable is "Teacher", I want the toolTip to be an explanation for the teacher job. And that seems hard to me if I separate them like that.

You can create an object which holds them both, tooltip and innerHTML.
E.g. :
teacher = {tooltip: "teacherTooltip", innerHtml: "<b>Teacher</b>"}
<div [matTooltip]="teacher.toolTip" [innerHTML]="teacher.innerHTML">

That fixed everything for me. Thank you so much, very easy and good explanations.
